# If $f: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, $f(z) \neq 0$ and $U=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |f(z)|<1\}$ then the connected components of $U$ are unbounded

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help understanding the proof of the following result:

> If $f: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic, $f(z) \neq 0$ and $U=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |f(z)|<1\}$ then the connected components of $U$ are unbounded.

The proof is as follows:

> Assume $\Omega$ is a bounded connected component of $U$. Connected components are also always closed so $\Omega$ is compact, and because $\partial \Omega$ is disjoint from $\Omega$ we must have $|f|=1$ on $\partial \Omega$.
> Moreover, $1/f$ is also analytic on $\Omega$ and $|1/f| = 1$ on $\partial \Omega$ so by the maximum modulus principle we have $|1/f| \le 1$ on $\Omega$. This implies $|f|\ge 1$ on $\Omega$, which is a contradiction.

I don't quite understand why we must have $|f|=1$ on $\partial \Omega$. Also, the conclusion seems a bit rushed and I would appreciate if someone can maybe explain in more detail. In particular, I don't see how $\Omega$ is open to be able to apply maximum modulus principle.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I believe your proof is in error from the second sentence. Connected components are closed subsets of the spaces of which they are components. So $\Omega$ is only a closed (bounded) subset of $U$, not a closed (bounded) subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and therefore not necessarily compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that most of your uncertainty will be due to the fact that part of the proof is simply wrong.

**Lemma**: if $\Omega$ is a connected component of $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, then $\Omega$ is open.

This should be an straightforward exercise in the definitions of connectedness and the subspace topology given the setting of $\mathbb{C}$. More generally, the connected components of open sets are open for [locally connected spaces](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Component_of_Locally_Connected_Space_is_Open).

Therefore, $\Omega$ is certainly not compact. Indeed, if it were, it would also be closed (as a subset of a Hausdorff space) which would make the proof's assertion that $\partial \Omega \cap \Omega = \emptyset$ absurd.

But since $\Omega$ is open, we do have that $\partial \Omega \cap \Omega = \emptyset$. Let $z \in \partial \Omega$. Then:

$$z \not \in U \implies |f(z)| \ge 1$$

On the other hand, $z \in \partial \Omega$ so $\exists z_n \in \Omega$ s.t. $ z_n \to z$. In particular, $z_n \in U \implies |f(z_n)| < 1$ and $|f|$ is continuous so:

$$|f(z_n)| \to |f(z)| \implies |f(z)| \le 1$$

We deduce $z \in \partial \Omega \implies |f(z)| = 1$ as claimed.

We can then apply the maximum modulus principle to the open set $\Omega$ in the way described.